# Flutter: Run {action} when http request takes more than 4 seconds

Tags: flutter, http

I want to display a snackbar that says "your internet connection is slow" when an api request takes more than 4 seconds even while the request is still running in the background, just to notify the user that his connection is too slow. I've tried wrapping the request with a stopwatch but that only works after the connection gets a response, which is too late. As the Future request is running, i'd like to know how many seconds its taking so i can run the snackbar display to view. I'd appreciate any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Hie there Moyosola.

**1. If you want it to just check the 4 second period**

To achieve this you can use a timer then cancel it once the time has passed, and notify the user. Check the code below. Call the method startTimer() when you start calling you api.

```
Timer _timer; // set as global variable
int _timeElapsed = 0;

void startTimer() {
const period = const Duration(seconds: 4);

_timer = new Timer.periodic(
  period,
  (Timer timer) {
    if (_timeElapsed == 5) {
      _timer.cancel();

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text('Your Internet Connection Is Slow')));

    } else {
        setState(() {
        _timeElapsed++;
      });
    }
  },
);
```

}

**2. If you want it to timeout**

To achieve that you need to wrap your code or whatever you want to run in a try-catch block on throw an onTimeoutException error after your set time has expired. See the code below:

```
   try {

       //put whatever you are running here and add timeout to http request

       await http.get(url).timeout(Duration(seconds: 4));

     } on TimeoutException catch (e, s) {

         //show any error after timeout here

         ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text('Your Internet Connection Is Slow')));
   }
}
```

I debug and answer people's questions also on my youtube channel, [Mufungo Geeks Programming](https://www.youtube.com/c/MufungoGeeks/), which might help you in other related queries. Good Day!